# Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1" Atom Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, atom-editor, vnc-server

I have an Amazon EC2 instance that runs Ubuntu 16.04 server. I installed atom and for some reason I am not able to start Atom. Everytime I start atom with the command line I see the following

```
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
```

I used vnc to setup ubuntu desktop and I am using vncviewer to access the desktop and start atom.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My vncconfig file looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

Answer (score 20):

This is good in general if you use headless VM;

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
cp libxcb.so.1 libxcb.so.1.bak
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' libxcb.so.1
```

It will fix all apps with same error

**Reason:**

Quoting from this link https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4360#issuecomment-189942757 :

> I was seeing the same error message and debugged it down to an X extension "BIG-REQUESTS". You can use xtrace to trace all the X traffic and I saw an 8MB message before it crashed.
> I first disabled all extensions with (xtrace -e ) and that worked.
> My final hack was to copy libxcb.so.1 into /usr/share/atom, open up in editor, and change 'BIG-REQUESTS' to '_IG-REQUESTS'. I figure when the client library asks if this extension is supported it will reply no and no more big messages.
> hope this helps

Comment: would you be able to explain what these commands do? It does a find/replace to swap "BIG-REQUESTS" for "_IG-REQUESTS", but what does that mean? And what is the function of libxcb.so.1?

Comment: Patching in binaries without any explanation whatsoever is bad.

Comment: First test if this is even a problem by running command `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 | grep REQUEST`.

Comment: Works like a charm for VS Code 1.15 on raspbian.

Comment: Check if this file is a symbolic link in your system. On Debian 16, this fix caused a later complaint during do-release-upgrade:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Answer (score 3):

I still get the error in command prompt but I am able to start atom

Thanks to this guy https://www.zhukun.net/archives/8070

This is what I did

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 /opt/atom/

sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' libxcb.so.1
```

and then

```
cd /opt/atom
./atom
```

The output of this being

```
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

But Atom did start as expected!! This is what I wanted.

Comment: Worked for me as well ! Thanks