# Error opening atom on Linux server accessed w/ XFCE and xRDP

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor, xfce, xrdp

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on a remote server and accessing via XFCE and xRDP through Microsoft Remote Desktop Application on a Mac High Sierra machine.

I've downloaded and installed Atom, however when opening via xfce Desktop nothing happens and no error is displayed; when opening via terminal using command `$ atom` I get the following output:

```
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".
```

This is all after installing and attempting to open Microsoft Visual Studio with the same results.

I was able to find a recent question about the [same issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210972/xlib-extension-xinputextension-missing-on-display-1-atom-ubuntu) and an [older question here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11884) however the fixes given didn't work for me.

Comment: FYI, I had the same error and the first SO link you posted worked for me.